# Hide Header and make appear on hover

Tags: jquery, css

So I have quite a bit of Jquery in the website already, I seem to have a habit of breaking the current code when adding bits.

But I have added a downward arrow into the header, I want to use CSS to hide the entire header minus the arrows, which when hovered over with the cursor, would make the entire header slide out.

I think I have most of the code needed to make this happen, however I am unsure of how I need to edit this, do I need to duplicate the code or just put this within another Div, and use a minus value?

The page; http://outside.hobhob.uk/test

The code I am looking at;

```
    <header id="header" role="banner">
        <div class="headwidth">
            <h1 class="logo">
                <?php
                    if (!empty($data['iter_normal_site_logo'])) {
                ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $data['iter_normal_site_logo']; ?>"></a>
                <?php 
                    } else {
                    ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </h1>
            <nav id="main-nav">
            <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' =>'main-nav','fallback_cb'=>'default_main_nav','container'=>'wda','depth'=>2,'menu_class'=>'sf-menu')); ?>
        </nav>  
        </div>
<center><img src="http://outside.hobhob.uk/test/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/duas-setas-apontando-para-baixo-em-angulo_318-54897.jpg"></center>
    </header>
```

And the CSS I am looking at;

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:9;
    padding-top: 50px;
    background-color:#fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #aaa;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #aaa;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #aaa;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

I am guessing I will need to add code similar to what I have put below, but I am unsure of what current code I will need to change in order to make this work smoothly?

```
#slideout {
  position: fixed;
  top: -250px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s
```

;

Comment: Take a look at the demo on this link: http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/. I'm assuming it's similar to what you're looking for

Comment: If the hover is on the arrow, you should put your image outside header, and hide header with css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you at liberty to rearrange the DOM? Because if you are you can apply the solution below.

**HTML**

```
<header id="header" role="banner">
    <center id="showHeader">
        <img src="http://outside.hobhob.uk/test/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/duas-setas-apontando-para-baixo-em-angulo_318-54897.jpg">
        <div class="headwidth">
            <h1 class="logo"><a href="http://outside.hobhob.uk/test"><img src="http://outside.hobhob.uk/test/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/logo2anismaller.gif"></a></h1>
            <nav id="main-nav">
                <ul id="menu-main" class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-shadow">
                    <li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item menu-item-50"><a href="http://outside.hobhob.uk/test/">Work</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-56" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-56"><a href="http://outside.hobhob.uk/test/?page_id=54">About</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-51"><a href="http://outside.hobhob.uk/test/?page_id=8">Workshops</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-52"><a href="http://outside.hobhob.uk/test/?page_id=10">Testimonials</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-53" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-53"><a href="http://outside.hobhob.uk/test/?page_id=12">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>        
            </nav>  
        </div>
    </center>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
center#showHeader > img:hover + .headwidth {
    height: 182px;
}

.headwidth {
    transition: .7s;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The trick here is to arrange the DOM, so that you can set-up your selectors in a way that'll give you the end result you're expecting when you declare the `:hover` state rule on the `img` in question.

Run the code snippet below to get the idea.

```css
center#showHeader > img:hover + .headwidth {
    height: 182px;
}

.headwidth {
    transition: .7s;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<header id="header" role="banner">
 <center id="showHeader">
  <img src="http://outside.hobhob.uk/test/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/duas-setas-apontando-para-baixo-em-angulo_318-54897.jpg">
  <div class="headwidth">
         <h1 class="logo"><a href="http://outside.hobhob.uk/test"><img src="http://outside.hobhob.uk/test/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/logo2anismaller.gif"></a></h1>
            <nav id="main-nav">
    <ul id="menu-main" class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-shadow">
     <li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item menu-item-50"><a href="http://outside.hobhob.uk/test/">Work</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-56" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-56"><a href="http://outside.hobhob.uk/test/?page_id=54">About</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-51"><a href="http://outside.hobhob.uk/test/?page_id=8">Workshops</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-52"><a href="http://outside.hobhob.uk/test/?page_id=10">Testimonials</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-53" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-53"><a href="http://outside.hobhob.uk/test/?page_id=12">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>        
   </nav> 
        </div>
 </center>
</header>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for what I needed, I kept most of the code the same on the theme file but that little shift on the css and styling worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: @DanielHobbs Glad to see it worked out for you, just had another look at the site and it functions well.

Comment: I'm not sure if I changed something.. But when I remove the cursor away from the arrow, it hides again, how would I keep it open while the cursor is on the header?

Here's how I have it currently.  http://pastie.org/10884551

Comment: Oh! Just add `.headwidth:hover` as an additional selector to the same `:hover` rule; so: `center#showHeader > img:hover + .headwidth, .headwidth:hover`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.
Sorry but ask, but one more little question, how would I make the entire top bar hover-able, rather than just the arrow? But while keeping the arrow there?

Comment: Target the parent element of the image instead, assuming it's set to display as a block, with no explicitly defined width values, it will naturally occupy the full-width of the parent element, which should be set to `100%`

Answer (score 2):

make your header `<header id="header" role="banner" style="display:none">`

and apply css as

```
#header:hover{
    display:block
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You said you have quite a bit of jQuery in your code so one solution could be to continue on that track, by checking wether your arrow is clicked, and if it is, add a class. See [this](http://pastebin.com/51Gdi5rS). (even although I am aware you want to use CSS, its still something that **should** work)

A alternative to that would be to split the code up from that pastebin, run the same JQuery code twice where one is mouseover and other one is mouseleave, then you just add and remove the class instead of toggling it, something like [this](http://pastebin.com/ghj2pZnH) (not tested however).

Answer (score 0):

display:none; removes the element from dom.

For those who want it to be in dom, use:

`<header id="header" role="banner" style="visibility:hidden">`

and on hover

```
#header:hover{
    visibility: visible
}
```